# Difficulty Centering Image on C# Winform Button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I'm trying to add a picture to a small button on my `winform`.  I can add the image alright, but it seems that no matter what I do the image will not center.

The size of the button is `30 x 24px`, and I measured the uniform grayspace on the button to be `27 x 21px`.  I have tried changing the value of the `ImageAlign` property, as well as increasing and decreasing the size of my graphic, but nothing seems to work.  The size of the graphic in the screen capture below is `27 x 21px`, which includes a `1px` gray border in the graphic.

This is as close as I've been able to get, but as you can see, instead of centering the image in the button, VS has it shifted down and right by `1px`.  Any thoughts or help here would be great.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the image you want to add to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with `Padding` properties of `Button` and you will get it center if it is possible.
By possible I mean if for example `height` of image is 16px and `height` of button is 27, then image always will be 1px above of center or 1px lower then center.